# Hi, I have this homework assignment for this class I'm retaking, the problem I'm running into is that I'm over-thinking the solution

Tags: java

I have to create a program that converts input string  for example "1onetwo34six5" output should be **"one12threefour6five"**
How to write this code i know how to convert number to word

```
static String digitToWord(char ch) {
    switch(ch) {    
    case '0': return "Zero";
    case '1': return "One";
    case '2': return "Two";
    case '3': return "Three";
    case '4': return "Four";
    case '5': return "Five";
    case '6': return "Six";
    case '7': return "Seven";
    case '8': return "Eight";
    case '9': return "Nine";
    }
    return "Unknown (" + ch + ")";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a good start. You are more likely to get assistance if you post all of your code, and then ask very specific questions about the code that does not work the way you want. In other words, solve as much of the problem on your own, and show that you've done that, and then ask for assistance on the part you can't figure out.

Comment: If you're afraid to be "overthinking" the solution what did you come up with? We could then provide hints on whether that's appropriate or not. Besides that didn't you get any hints/help as how to approach this? I'd say the goal of the assignment is to teach you to think about a way to solve this rather than just writing code (with us providing a solution).

Comment: One hint for your solution: if `1` should be converted to `one` and vice versa you shouldn't return `"One"` but `"one"` etc. Besides that a mapping like yours seems reasonable enough. I'd suggest you provide a similar method for the reverse mapping and  working with strings as input as well (so `"1"` is mapped to `"one"` and vice versa). The main problem would then be to split your input into the correct parts, especially the consecutive strings like `"onetwo"` - do you have an idea on how to do that already?

Comment: hi thomas, i am having problem with string i'm storing "one" to "ten" in array and using for loop i am checking condition if that array is in main string

Answer (score 0):

You need to enhance logic for parsing the incoming string first: decide whether you need to transform a number to a string, or a string to a number.

What is more complex for the second case is that you need to understand where is the limit for number words. For example, how do you know where one number string ends in "onetwo"?

For the specific part you posted, it is better to store mapping from number to string in a map. Switch is more prone to errors and is more difficult to support later on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer but you can do something like this:

```
String Converter(String stringToConvert){
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("1","One");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("2","Two");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("3","Three");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("4","Four");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("5","Five");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("6","Six");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("7","Seven");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("8","Eight");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("9","Nine");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("one","1");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("two","2");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("three","3");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("four","4");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("five","5");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("six","6");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("seven","7");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("eight","8");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.replace("nine","9");
    stringToConvert = stringToConvert.toLowerCase();
    return stringToConvert;
}
```

Notice I used `toLowerCase` at the end to keep the format the same

Comment: what to write in stringToConvert

Comment: stringToConvert is the input string to the method. in your case "1onetwo34six5"

Comment: But whenever we are trying to change string format (string is immutable) we have to assign to different string and concat it with replaced string

Comment: Thank you but I'm able to run the code and get output

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm comes first, if the data is in principle clear.

```
String convert(String text) {
    ...
    String result = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < text.length()) {
        int foundAndTranslated = findTranslation(text.substring(i));
        result += translated(foundAndTranslated);
        i += foundLength(foundAndTranslated);
    }
    return result;
}
```

At some point in the string you are looking for "1" or "one" and want to replace that with "one" or "1". The above mirrors that.

This strongly suggests to me, that instead of char '1' a String "1" would be simpler, to keep `{"1", "one"}` and `{"one", "1"}`.

Then one should consider garbage like "y" to be of length 1 to continue, resulting in "y" or "?".

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with string numerical digits from **"0"** to **"9"** and numerical names from **"zero"** to **"nine"** then one way you can do this is to **split** the input string into their respective elements.

Since the string numerical digits (1 to 9) and the numerical names (zero - nine) are unique in their representation this can be done utilizing a Two Dimensional (2D) String Array (or whatever collection method you like), a List Interface and a couple **for** loops, like this:

```
String[][] numbers = {{"one","1"}, {"two", "2"}, {"three","3"},
                      {"four", "4"}, {"five", "5"}, {"six","6"},
                      {"seven", "7"}, {"eight", "8"}, {"nine", "9"},
                      {"zero", "0"}};

String strg = "1onetwo34six5";
System.out.println("Original String: " + strg);

// Split the input string into String digits and numerical Names
String tmp = "";
List<String> splitList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < strg.length(); i++) {
    String s = strg.substring(i, i+1);
    // Is the character a digit (0 to 9)?
    if (s.matches("\\d")) {
        // Yes it is...
        splitList.add(s);   // Add it to the splitList.
    }
    // Nope...it must be a numerical name.
    else {
        tmp+= s;   // Start creating the numerical name.
        /* Is the numerical name created thus far contained
           within the numbers 2D String Array?  */
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (tmp.toLowerCase().equals(numbers[j][0])) {
                // Yes...It's here. Add it to the splitList
                splitList.add(tmp);
                tmp = "";  // Clear tmp in prep for the next numerical word.
                break;     // Get out of loop. No longer needed for this word.
            }
        }
        // Nope...get the next character.
    }
}
```

Once the **split** is acquired it is now a simple matter of comparing each split element from the input string to the elements contained within the 2D String Array and applying the appropriate elemental string value, like this:

```
/* The splitList List now contains what we need.
   It's just a matter of converting each element
   to its' represented value which we hold in the 
   numbers String Array and build a string from it. */
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String element : splitList) {
    // Is it a numerical digit?
    if (element.matches("\\d")) {
        //Yes...it is so append its' respective numerical name to sb.
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (element.equals(numbers[i][1])) {
                sb.append(numbers[i][0]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Nope...it must be a numerical Name.
    else {
        // Append its' respective numerical digit to sb.
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (element.toLowerCase().equals(numbers[i][0])) {
                sb.append(numbers[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
// Display the modified input string.
System.out.println("Modified String: " + sb.toString());
```

If you want to deal with whitespaces within the input string then I think you can easily figure out what is required here and make the necessary modifications.